# Can someone explain how to find and use kext files?

Tags: display, cinema-display

The post I found on this forum: "Apple Cinema Display Brightness no longer works in Mavericks or Yosemite" explains how to fix it using kext files but I can't figure out how to get the kext file to use with the KextBeast program. I bought a used Apple LED Cinema Display and need to be able to adjust brightness to calibrate it.

Comment: to find all kext files type "mdfind .kext" in Terminal. Beyond that you are entering dangerous ground, but you know that! do you ?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that by also plugging in the usb cord from my monitor to the computer, the brightness controls on my keyboard now work! No need for kext files after all.